# How can I convert Lat-Long to FIPS county code without problems in R?

Tags: python, r, geospatial, spatial

I have thousands of Lat-long points and I used this code to convert it into FIPS county codes.

```
latlong2county <- function(pointsDF) {
# Prepare SpatialPolygons object with one SpatialPolygon
# per state (plus DC, minus HI & AK)
states <- map('county', fill=TRUE, col="transparent", plot=FALSE)
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(states$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
states_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(states, IDs=IDs,
                               proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=wgs84"))

# Convert pointsDF to a SpatialPoints object 
pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(pointsDF, 
                        proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=wgs84"))

# Use 'over' to get _indices_ of the Polygons object containing each point 
indices <- over(pointsSP, states_sp)

# Return the state names of the Polygons object containing each point
stateNames <- sapply(states_sp@polygons, function(x) x@ID)
stateNames[indices]
}

data(county.fips)
latlon <- data.frame(all$lon,all$lat)
county<-latlong2county(latlon)
fips<-with(county.fips, fips[match(county, polyname)])
```

But, the problem with this is it is not converting all lat-longs to FIPS codes. I get NA values for legitimate counties. Can anyone help with it?

Or simply suggest a different solution?

Comment: The polygons in the **maps** package are of quite low resolution. If you haven't yet, you should check (by plotting) that those points that return NA are actually located in the proper counties.

Comment: Your best best is the gov api : http://www.fcc.gov/developers/census-block-conversions-api

Answer (score 1):

although this solution isn't python-based, you could use ruby and the [geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit) gem to pre-process your data, then pass it to R via csv file or other means.

see this [write-up](http://mattdickenson.com/2012/11/14/how-to-get-fips-codes-from-latitude-and-longitude/) for further instructions.